# Phonegap plugin record audio

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create an android plugin for phonegap that start recording noise and when the user starts speaking stops the noise recording and starts a new record for voice.

I have been able to make it work in android but when I try to add it as a phonegap plugin it doesn't work.

The code is as follows:

**RecordVoice.js**

```
var RecordVoice = {
 startRecord: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    cordova.exec(
        successCallback, // success callback function
        errorCallback, // error callback function
        'RecordVoice', // mapped to our native Java class called     "RecordVoicePlugin"
        'startrecording'); 
 }
}
module.exports = RecordVoice;
```

**RecordVoice.java**

```
    package org.maria.RecordVoice;  
    import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
    import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import com.androidexample.noisealert.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class NoiseAlert extends CordovaPlugin  {
    public static final String ACTION_ADD_RECORD_ENTRY = "startrecording";
        /* constants */
            private static final int POLL_INTERVAL = 300;

            /** running state **/
            private boolean mRunning = false;

            /** config state **/
            private int mThreshold;

            private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

            private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

            /* References to view elements */
            private TextView mStatusView;
            private SoundLevelView mDisplay;

            /* sound data source */

        private  boolean thesholdReached =false;
        @Override
        public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
            try {
                if (ACTION_ADD_RECORD_ENTRY.equals(action)) { 
                    JSONObject arg_object = args.getJSONObject(0);

                 cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                          double amp = getAmplitude();

                            //Log.i("Noise", "runnable mPollTask");
                            updateDisplay(amp, amp);

                            if ((amp > mThreshold)) {
                                  //start();

                                if(thesholdReached==false) {
                                    stop();
                                    startrecordingvoice();
                                    // Show alert when noise thersold crossed
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Noise Thersold Crossed, do here your stuff.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    //callForHelp();
                                    //Log.i("Noise", "==== onCreate ===");
                                    thesholdReached=true;
                                }
                            }

                         callbackContext.success(); 
                    }
                }

                   return true;
                }
                callbackContext.error("Invalid action");
                return false;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
                return false;
            } 
        }


            private void start() {

                    startrecordingnoise();
                    if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                            mWakeLock.acquire();
                    }

                    //Noise monitoring start
                    // Runnable(mPollTask) will execute after POLL_INTERVAL
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mPollTask, POLL_INTERVAL);
            }

            private void stop() {
                Log.i("Noise", "==== Stop Noise Monitoring===");
                    if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                            mWakeLock.release();
                    }
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mSleepTask);
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mPollTask);

                if (mRecorder != null) {
                    mRecorder.stop();
                    mRecorder.release();
                    mRecorder = null;
                }
                    mDisplay.setLevel(0,0);

                    mRunning = false;

            }


            private void initializeApplicationConstants() {
                    // Set Noise Threshold
                    mThreshold = 8;

            }

            private void updateDisplay(double ampl, double signalEMA) {
                    mStatusView.setText(Double.toString(ampl));
                    // 
                    mDisplay.setLevel((int)signalEMA, mThreshold);
            }


            private void callForHelp() {

                stop();
                startrecordingvoice();
                 // Show alert when noise thersold crossed
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Noise Thersold Crossed, do here your stuff.",
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        // This file is used to record voice
        static final private double EMA_FILTER = 0.6;

        private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
        private double mEMA = 0.0;

        public void startrecordingnoise() {

            if (mRecorder == null) {
                String outputFile = null;
                outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/NoiseRecording.amr";

                mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                //mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
                mRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

                try {
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mRecorder.start();
                mEMA = 0.0;
            }
        }
        public void startrecordingvoice() {

            if (mRecorder == null) {
                String outputFile = null;
                outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/VoiceRecording.amr";

                mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                //mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
                mRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

                try {
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mRecorder.start();
                mEMA = 0.0;
            }
        }


        public double getAmplitude() {
            if (mRecorder != null)
                return  (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()/2700.0);
            else
                return 0;

        }

        public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
            double amp = getAmplitude();
            mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
            return mEMA;
        }

    };
```

**index.js**

```
            var app = {
                // Application Constructor
                initialize: function() {
                    this.bindEvents();
                },
                // Bind Event Listeners
                //
                // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
                // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
                bindEvents: function() {
                    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
                },
                // deviceready Event Handler
                //
                // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
                // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
                onDeviceReady: function() {
                    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
                    app.addToCal();
                },
                // Update DOM on a Received Event
                receivedEvent: function(id) {
                    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
                    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
                    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

                    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
                    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

                    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
                },
            addToCal: function() {

                    var success = function() { alert("Success"); };
                    var error = function(message) { alert("Oopsie! " + message); };
                    RecordVoice.startRecord(success, error);
            }
            };
```

**plugin.xml**

```
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
       id="org.maria.RecordVoice"
  version="0.1.0">
<name>RecordVoice</name>
<description>Sample PhoneGap RecordVoice Plugin</description>
<license>MIT</license>
<keywords>phonegap,RecordVoice</keywords>


<js-module src="www/RecordVoice.js" name="RecordVoice">
    <clobbers target="window.RecordVoice" />
</js-module>

<!-- android -->
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="RecordVoice">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.maria.RecordVoice.RecordVoice"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/android/RecordVoice.java" target-dir="src/org/maria/RecordVoice" />      
 </platform>
```

Any idea why it's not working?
Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

In your *RecordVoice.js* file try to add empty array [] to exec function:

```
var RecordVoice = {
 startRecord: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
 cordova.exec(
    successCallback, // success callback function
    errorCallback, // error callback function
    'RecordVoice', // mapped to our native Java class called "RecordVoicePlugin"
    'startrecording',
    []
 ); 
}
}
module.exports = RecordVoice;
```